# ¿Cómo excluir con preg_match este caracter \t ? PHP

Tags: php, regex

Tengo este texto extraido desde los correos electronicos, pero me los devuelve con el \t y no logro como extraer el email o el nombre

```
CLIENTE\t:\tVoldi\n
EMAIL\t:\tharrypotter@warner.com\n
PROYECTO\t:\tLas reliquias de la muerte\n
```

No se como hacer la construcción de la expresion regular, generalmente lo hacía de esta forma, porque ningun correo me mostraba los \t, pero este mensaje me los trae.

```
preg_match('/CLIENTE    :(.*)/', $text, $nombre);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casualmente, se te está mostrando los caracteres sin interpretar. `\t` equivale a un tabulador (8 espacios) y `\n` a una nueva línea. Por eso, el `preg_match` intenta eliminar el tabulador, no el **carácter** `\` y la letra `t` juntas. Para eso deberías usar un escape en la *contrabarra* de esta manera:

```php
$a = 'Hola\t, qué tal.';
echo $a;

if (preg_match('/\\t/', $a) == 1) {
    echo 'Encontrado.';
} else {
    echo 'No encontrado';
}
```

Fíjate que en este caso las comillas simples son relevantes, ya que toman el contenido como texto literal y no lo interpretan.

Comment: Me funciono con 2 /\\t/ gracias :D

Comment: Perdona, errata al escribir.. Me alegro que te haya ido bien.